# Encountered undefined provider (angular4)

Tags: angular

i work on angular4 and i've been fighting for several days with this mistake :

```
Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular
 dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.
```

thought it was related to injecting services (`providers: [services, ...]`) or components into `@ngModule`. I changed everything and checked it out, but it doesn't change anything. Where can this mistake come from?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, I post it here in case people have the same problem.
If you are on a big project like mine with several people. Don't forget to update your nodes_modules locally:

> rm -rf node_modules/ (on master or dev...)
>
> npm cache clean -f
>
> npm i (to install everything)

once the master branch has been updated you can update your branch :

> git rebase master

Solved conflicts and it's over.